# Correct code improvement

Tags: mysql, procedure

Can somebody look at my code ,because I dont know if its OK or no in MySQL

```
set @max=concat('select max(length(CommentsId))from', table_name);
    prepare stmt from @max;
    execute stmt;

    set @max=concat('UPDATE', table_name, 'SET CommentsId= ',CommentsId * power(10, (@max - length(CommentsId))),' WHERE CommentsId= ', @CommentsId );
    prepare stmt from @max;
    execute stmt;
```

Comment: What do you want it to do? What does it do when you run it? How are these things different?

Comment: Just a suggestion here, but the best way to know if _its OK or no_ is to try it.

Answer (score 0):

You need spaces before or after your `from`, `UPDATE`, and `SET` keywords.

```
set @max=concat('select max(length(CommentsId)) from ', table_name);
prepare stmt from @max;
execute stmt;

set @max=concat('UPDATE ', table_name, ' SET CommentsId= ',CommentsId * power(10, (@max -   length(CommentsId))),' WHERE CommentsId= ', @CommentsId );
prepare stmt from @max;
execute stmt;
```